# dropzone.js programmatically doesn't work

Tags: javascript, jquery, dropzone.js

I am trying create drop zones programmatically, but it doesn't work.

HTML Code:

```
<div class="content-wrap">
   <div class="row">
      <script type="text/javascript">
         $(function() {
            $("div#myDropZone").dropzone({
                url : "/file-upload"
            });
         });
      </script>
      <div class="col-sm-12">
         <div class="nest" id="DropZoneClose">
            <div class="title-alt">
               <h6>DropZone</h6>
            </div>
            <div class="body-nest" id="DropZone">
               <div id="myDropZone" >
               </div>
               <button style="margin-top: 10px;" class="btn btn-info"
                  id="submit-all">Submit all files</button>
            </div>
         </div>
      </div>
   </div>
</div>
```

The drop zone in `<div id="myDropZone">` not appers!

best regards :)

Answer (score 19, accepted):

You need to give your `#myDropZone` div some width and height so that it takes up space. Heres a [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/2F565/1/).

Alternatively, you can add the `dropzone` class to your div to get the default styling that you see in the demos. Heres the [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/2F565/2/) for that.

Comment: go-oleg 

Just one more question. 

I have a form and inside my drop zone. 

Why I need the url parameter: "/ file-upload"? 
Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Add class `dropzone` to the `div` element which holds your drop zone.
Hope that you have added the `dropzone` stylesheet to your page.